# How can I export a txt file from an Excel sheet without having a blank line at the end?

Tags: excel, vba, txt

When I export a sheet as txt it generates an empty line at the end.
[image: incorrect txt file]

What I need
[image]

I use this code to detect the used range and only export that. It is necessary to have the workbook with the data to copy open.

```vb
Sub export_range_txt()
    
    Workbooks.Add
    y = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    'insert the name of the workbook were data is been copied and create  this sub there
    Windows("original.xlsm").Activate 
    ActiveSheet.Activate
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
    Range("A1:Y" & LastRow).Copy
    Windows(y).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Activate
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'change path to desired location of the txt file
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
      "path\test.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, _
      CreateBackup:=False

    ActiveWindow.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you share the code you used to export the worksheet? You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71805536/edit) at any time.

Comment: @VBasic2008 sure, my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will export a range to a text file without a blank line at the end.

```
Function exportRgToTxt(rg As Range, filename As String)

    ' use a semicolon as a column separator, adjust accordingly or use a parameter
    Const SEPARATOR = ";"

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim vdat As Variant, vRow As Variant
        
    ' Placing the values of the range into an array
    vdat = rg.Value

    Dim txtFile As Long
    txtFile = FreeFile
    Open filename For Output As txtFile
        
    ' Write each row of the range to the text file but the last one
    For i = LBound(vdat, 1) To UBound(vdat, 1) - 1
        vRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(vdat, i, 0)  ' Get the i-th row of the array
        vRow = Join(vRow, SEPARATOR)
        Print #txtFile, vRow   ' This will add a CRLF at the end of the line
    Next i
    
    ' Write Last row without an CRLF
    vRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(vdat, UBound(vdat, 1), 0)
    vRow = Join(vRow, SEPARATOR)
    Print #txtFile, vRow; ' the semicolon will avoid the CRLF at the end of the file
    Close txtFile

End Function
```

Be aware, the function will fail in case the range contains a single cell only. One could adjust it but I leave that to the reader.

That's how you can test it

```
Sub testit()
    exportRgToTxt Range("A1").CurrentRegion, "D:\tmp\abc.txt"
End Sub
```

Further reading on the [Print Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/printstatement). Especially the *charpos* parameter is the one we need here

***charpos***
*Specifies the insertion point for the next character. **Use a semicolon to position the insertion point immediately after the last character displayed.** Use Tab(n) to position the insertion point to an absolute column number. Use Tab with no argument to position the insertion point at the beginning of the next print zone. **If charpos is omitted, the next character is printed on the next line**.*

See below how one could use the function in the OP's code

```
Sub export_range_txt()
    
    Workbooks.Add
    y = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    'insert the name of the workbook were data is been copied and create  this sub there
    Windows("original.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Activate
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    'Range("A1:Y" & LastRow).Copy  ' this line is not needed any longer
    
    ' Here you could use the exportRgToTxt instead
    exportRgToTxt Range("A1:Y" & LastRow), "<your file name>"
    
    
    ' the remaining code is not neccessary
'    Windows(y).Activate
'    ActiveSheet.Activate
'    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
'
'
'
'    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
'   'change path to desired location of the txt file
'        "path\test.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, _
'    CreateBackup:=False
'    ActiveWindow.Close
'    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! works like a charm, I tried it with one row and one column only and it also worked perfectly, just one last question should I edit my question to include the answer? I'm new to stackoverflow and want to do things the right way to help others, thanks!

Comment: Everything is fine, you did it in the right way by marking the answer

Comment: I have another question regarding a more complex integration of this code, in this form it functions properly but when integrated with another one it has the follow error: type 13 types dont match, should post another question? or just update this one?

Comment: it apears in the line vRow = Join(vRow, SEPARATOR). it appears to be that i have columns with general, date, hour and text formats, so that affects the data of the array?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know anything about your "comply integration". I'd suggest to create a new post with corresponding information.

Comment: Thank you I already create the post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71806957/error-13-types-dont-match-trying-to-export-as-an-array-different-columns-with if you are free to check it out that would be great