# Error 13: types dont match, trying to export as an array different columns with differente data formats: general, text, hour, date

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
   Sub eliminar_linea_vba()

    
    Dim ColaDeImpresion As Range
    Set ColaDeImpresion = Workbooks("Buscador.xlsm").Worksheets("Hoja Lista de Impresión").Rows("4:295")
    
    Dim DatosActualizados As Range
    Set DatosActualizados = Workbooks("ConexionBartenderV2.xlsm").Worksheets("DatosActualizados").Range("A4")
    
    Dim Filtrado As Range
    Set Filtrado = Workbooks("ConexionBartenderV2.xlsm").Worksheets("Filtrado").Range("A4:Y100")
    
    Dim GenerarEtiqueta As Worksheet
    Set GenerarEtiqueta = Workbooks("ConexionBartenderV2.xlsm").Worksheets("GenerarEtiqueta")
    
    ColaDeImpresion.Copy DatosActualizados 
    Filtrado.Copy 
    GenerarEtiqueta.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats 
    GenerarEtiqueta.Range("A1:Y100").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0" '
    LastRow = GenerarEtiqueta.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
    exportRgToTxt Range("A1:Y" & LastRow), "C:\Users\artur\Desktop\Trigger\Trigger_vba.txt" 
   
End Sub

Function exportRgToTxt(rg As Range, filename As String)

    ' use a semicolon as a column separator, adjust accordingly or use a parameter
    Const SEPARATOR = vbTab

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim vdat As Variant, vRow As Variant
        
    ' Placing the values of the range into an array
    'vdat = rg.Value
    vdat = replaceError(rg.Value)       ' modification in case range contains #ERR

    Dim txtFile As Long
    txtFile = FreeFile
    Open filename For Output As txtFile
        
    ' Write each row of the range to the text file but the last one
    For i = LBound(vdat, 1) To UBound(vdat, 1) - 1
        vRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(vdat, i, 0)  ' Get the i-th row of the array
        vRow = Join(vRow, SEPARATOR) 'PROBLEM HERE
        Print #txtFile, vRow   ' This will add a CRLF at the end of the line
    Next i
    
    ' Write Last row without an CRLF
    vRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(vdat, UBound(vdat, 1), 0)
    vRow = Join(vRow, SEPARATOR)
    Print #txtFile, vRow; ' the tab will avoid the CRLF at the end of the file
    Close txtFile

End Function

Function replaceError(ByVal vdat As Variant) As Variant
    ' function will replace "error data" with blank
    ' or the corresponding string (uncomment accordingly)
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    For i = LBound(vdat, 1) To UBound(vdat, 1)
        For j = LBound(vdat, 2) To UBound(vdat, 2)
            If IsError(vdat(i, j)) Then
                ' vdat(i, j) = CStr(vdat(i, j))  ' uncomment if you want the error text
                vdat(i, j) = vbNullChar
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    replaceError = vdat

End Function
```

Data sample:

```
A1 = 12567789 (format:general)
B1 = 22/03/2024 (format:short date)
C1 = 18:00:21 (format:hour)
D1 = 15 (format:text)
E1 = lun(format:general) 
F1 = AEC F (format:general)
G1 = table (format:general)
H1 = 1 of 2 (format:text)
I1 = 165498 (format:general)
J1 = 187891 (format:general)
K1 = blank (format:general)
L1 = 210 (format:text)
M1 = cut (format:general) 
N1 = flare (format:general)
O1 = bend (format:general)
P1 = packing (format:general)
Q1 = #N/D (format:general)
R1 = #N/D (format:general)
S1 = #N/D (format:general)
T1 = #N/D (format:general)
U1 = #N/D (format:general)
V1 = #N/D (format:general)
W1 = 142mm (format:general)
X1 = 3/12 x 0.014 (format:general)
Y1 = ± 1.0 (format:general)
```

All lines are necessary, the problem happens in the indicated line and states error 13 not matching type. The only data that generates an issue are the ones that have a "#" in the cell, any idea of how to prevent this? or how to clear or substitue cells if they have speceffic data in them?

UPDATE: Column number three should be in hour format
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvMnY.png)

[correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2SNI.png)

Comment: What is the content of `vRow` and the data type of `vRow` when your macro stops at that point.  You forgot to add samples of your data so someone can reproduce your problem. Also, please clean up your code by getting rid of those unnecessary `Select`s and `Activate`s.  See [How to avoid Using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Sorry about that, I’ll update and include a txt sample file. Regarding the data type I’m not sure how to check that. I’ll clean the code and update it thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71805536/hi-how-con-i-export-a-txt-file-from-an-excel-sheet-without-having-a-blank-line/71806038?noredirect=1#comment126894264_71806038) to previous post for this topic.

The error is caused by previous errors you have in the worksheet. Data like `#N/D` is a sign that the formula in this cell caused an error. IMHO it doesn't really make sense to export this kind of data and you should fix these kind of errors beforehand.

But anyway, the following code will replace the error with blank

```
Function replaceError(ByVal vdat As Variant) As Variant
    ' function will replace "error data" with blank
    ' or the corresponding string (uncomment accordingly)
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    For i = LBound(vdat, 1) To UBound(vdat, 1)
        For j = LBound(vdat, 2) To UBound(vdat, 2)
            If IsError(vdat(i, j)) Then
                ' vdat(i, j) = CStr(vdat(i, j))  ' uncomment if you want the error text
                vdat(i, j) = vbNullChar
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    replaceError = vdat

End Function
```

The function `exportRgToTxt` needs the following modification

```
Function exportRgToTxt(rg As Range, filename As String)

    ' use a semicolon as a column separator, adjust accordingly or use a parameter
    Const SEPARATOR = ";"

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim vdat As Variant, vRow As Variant
        
    ' Placing the values of the range into an array
    'vdat = rg.Value
    vdat = replaceError(rg.Value)       ' modification in case range contains #ERR

    Dim txtFile As Long
    txtFile = FreeFile
    Open filename For Output As txtFile
        
    ' Write each row of the range to the text file but the last one
    For i = LBound(vdat, 1) To UBound(vdat, 1) - 1
        vRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(vdat, i, 0)  ' Get the i-th row of the array
        vRow = Join(vRow, SEPARATOR) 'PROBLEM HERE
        Print #txtFile, vRow   ' This will add a CRLF at the end of the line
    Next i
    
    ' Write Last row without an CRLF
    vRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(vdat, UBound(vdat, 1), 0)
    vRow = Join(vRow, SEPARATOR)
    Print #txtFile, vRow; ' the tab will avoid the CRLF at the end of the file
    Close txtFile

End Function
```

**Update:** In the case you want to keep the format of the data you cannot use any longer the approach with arrays

The following function will export the data as it is displayed in the worksheet including the errors like #N/D

```
Function exportRgToTxtA(rg As Range, filename As String)

    ' keep the format of the data when exporting
    ' it will also output the cells with #ERR
    
    ' unfortunately it is not possible to use vdat = rg.text
    ' unless rg is only a single cell

    ' use a semicolon as a column separator, adjust accordingly or use a parameter
    Const SEPARATOR = ";"

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim sngRow As Range

    Dim txtFile As Long
    txtFile = FreeFile
    Open filename For Output As txtFile
    
    ' looping through  each row of the range but the last one
    For i = 1 To rg.Rows.CountLarge - 1
        Set sngRow = rg.Rows(1)
        ' loopinng throught the columns of the row
        For j = 1 To sngRow.Columns.CountLarge
            Print #txtFile, sngRow.Cells(1, j).Text;
            ' add a SEPARATOR for all columns but not at the end
            If j < rg.Rows.CountLarge Then
                Print #txtFile, SEPARATOR;
            End If
        Next j
        ' add a CRLF at the end of the row
        Print #txtFile,   
    Next i
    
    ' writing the last row of the range to the text file
    ' a little bit differently
    Set sngRow = rg.Rows(rg.Rows.CountLarge)
    For j = 1 To sngRow.Columns.CountLarge - 1
        Print #txtFile, sngRow.Cells(1, j).Text;
        Print #txtFile, SEPARATOR;
    Next j
    Print #txtFile, sngRow.Cells(1, rg.Rows.CountLarge).Text

    Close txtFile

End Function
```

Comment: I have the same opinion, however those error fields may get data, it depends on the type of product the company references, I've thought of making it kind of modular but don't have the expertise for that.

The code works great, but it does not keep the hour format (info updated in post)

Comment: I updated the post but sooner or later you need to try something on your own and in case you get stuck post a question.

Comment: Sorry about it, I know, kind of new to this and my supervisor need it fast, thank you for your support

Comment: What does that men? Does the updated code not work? Or do you have another roadblock now?

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly, all good